# suggestion of library like django bootstrap toolkit using briliant HTML5 client side validation in all the produced forms

Tags: javascript, python, django, html, twitter-bootstrap

I recently discovered, how powerful HTML5 form's validation on client side is, and would like to use it in my django projects. Of course I am extremely lazy, and I love all the DRY ideas, so I look for something like django bootstrap toolkit but rendering to HTML5 validated forms.

UPDATE:

`bootstrap3` provides html5 validation on client side [[LINK]](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-floppyforms do HTML5 [client side validation](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/differences.html#client-side-validation). See [github](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-floppyforms) and [documentation](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: `bootstrap3` provieds html5 validation on client side https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3.